# oracle PL/SQL API call

Tags: sql, oracle, api, oracle-apps

I am trying to insert objectives for users through the HR_OBJECTIVES_API API call. Below is the sample call i am using:

```
/* Auto Generation of Script Start */
DECLARE
     -- Start of Variable declarations, Initialize Variables with appropriate values to test the script
     -- VARCHAR2 size is set to 2000 by default, please enter target table name to retrieve the exact limit
     -- Input Variables
     V_VALIDATE                      BOOLEAN:=false;
     V_EFFECTIVE_DATE                DATE := trunc(sysdate);
     V_BUSINESS_GROUP_ID             NUMBER:=81;
     V_NAME                          VARCHAR2(2000):='Just a Second test from TOAD';
     V_START_DATE                    DATE:=trunc(sysdate);
     V_OWNING_PERSON_ID              NUMBER:=264;
     V_TARGET_DATE                   DATE;
     V_ACHIEVEMENT_DATE              DATE;
     V_DETAIL                        VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_COMMENTS                      VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_SUCCESS_CRITERIA              VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_APPRAISAL_ID                  NUMBER;
     V_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY            VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE1                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE2                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE3                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE4                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE5                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE6                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE7                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE8                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE9                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE10                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE11                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE12                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE13                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE14                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE15                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE16                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE17                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE18                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE19                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE20                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE21                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE22                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE23                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE24                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE25                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE26                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE27                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE28                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE29                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_ATTRIBUTE30                   VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_SCORECARD_ID                  NUMBER:=9193;
     V_COPIED_FROM_LIBRARY_ID        NUMBER;
     V_COPIED_FROM_OBJECTIVE_ID      NUMBER;
     V_ALIGNED_WITH_OBJECTIVE_ID     NUMBER;
     V_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE              DATE;
     V_GROUP_CODE                    VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_PRIORITY_CODE                 VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_APPRAISE_FLAG                 VARCHAR2(2000):='Y';
     V_VERIFIED_FLAG                 VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_TARGET_VALUE                  NUMBER;
     V_ACTUAL_VALUE                  NUMBER;
     V_WEIGHTING_PERCENT             NUMBER;
     V_COMPLETE_PERCENT              NUMBER;
     V_UOM_CODE                      VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_MEASUREMENT_STYLE_CODE        VARCHAR2(2000):='N_M';
     V_MEASURE_NAME                  VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_MEASURE_TYPE_CODE             VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_MEASURE_COMMENTS              VARCHAR2(2000);
     V_SHARING_ACCESS_CODE           VARCHAR2(2000);
     -- Output Variables
     V_WEIGHTING_OVER_100_WARNING    BOOLEAN;
     V_WEIGHTING_APPRAISAL_WARNING   BOOLEAN;
     V_OBJECTIVE_ID                  NUMBER;
     V_OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER         NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_output.enable(800000);
     --  Calling API HR_OBJECTIVES_API.CREATE_OBJECTIVE
     HR_OBJECTIVES_API.CREATE_OBJECTIVE(P_VALIDATE                     => V_VALIDATE
                                       ,P_EFFECTIVE_DATE               => V_EFFECTIVE_DATE
                                       ,P_BUSINESS_GROUP_ID            => V_BUSINESS_GROUP_ID
                                       ,P_NAME                         => V_NAME
                                       ,P_START_DATE                   => V_START_DATE
                                       ,P_OWNING_PERSON_ID             => V_OWNING_PERSON_ID
                                       ,P_TARGET_DATE                  => V_TARGET_DATE
                                       ,P_ACHIEVEMENT_DATE             => V_ACHIEVEMENT_DATE
                                       ,P_DETAIL                       => V_DETAIL
                                       ,P_COMMENTS                     => V_COMMENTS
                                       ,P_SUCCESS_CRITERIA             => V_SUCCESS_CRITERIA
                                       ,P_APPRAISAL_ID                 => V_APPRAISAL_ID
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY           => V_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE1                   => V_ATTRIBUTE1
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE2                   => V_ATTRIBUTE2
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE3                   => V_ATTRIBUTE3
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE4                   => V_ATTRIBUTE4
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE5                   => V_ATTRIBUTE5
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE6                   => V_ATTRIBUTE6
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE7                   => V_ATTRIBUTE7
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE8                   => V_ATTRIBUTE8
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE9                   => V_ATTRIBUTE9
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE10                  => V_ATTRIBUTE10
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE11                  => V_ATTRIBUTE11
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE12                  => V_ATTRIBUTE12
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE13                  => V_ATTRIBUTE13
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE14                  => V_ATTRIBUTE14
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE15                  => V_ATTRIBUTE15
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE16                  => V_ATTRIBUTE16
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE17                  => V_ATTRIBUTE17
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE18                  => V_ATTRIBUTE18
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE19                  => V_ATTRIBUTE19
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE20                  => V_ATTRIBUTE20
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE21                  => V_ATTRIBUTE21
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE22                  => V_ATTRIBUTE22
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE23                  => V_ATTRIBUTE23
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE24                  => V_ATTRIBUTE24
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE25                  => V_ATTRIBUTE25
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE26                  => V_ATTRIBUTE26
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE27                  => V_ATTRIBUTE27
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE28                  => V_ATTRIBUTE28
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE29                  => V_ATTRIBUTE29
                                       ,P_ATTRIBUTE30                  => V_ATTRIBUTE30
                                       ,P_SCORECARD_ID                 => V_SCORECARD_ID
                                       ,P_COPIED_FROM_LIBRARY_ID       => V_COPIED_FROM_LIBRARY_ID
                                       ,P_COPIED_FROM_OBJECTIVE_ID     => V_COPIED_FROM_OBJECTIVE_ID
                                       ,P_ALIGNED_WITH_OBJECTIVE_ID    => V_ALIGNED_WITH_OBJECTIVE_ID
                                       ,P_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE             => V_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE
                                       ,P_GROUP_CODE                   => V_GROUP_CODE
                                       ,P_PRIORITY_CODE                => V_PRIORITY_CODE
                                       ,P_APPRAISE_FLAG                => V_APPRAISE_FLAG
                                       ,P_VERIFIED_FLAG                => V_VERIFIED_FLAG
                                       ,P_TARGET_VALUE                 => V_TARGET_VALUE
                                       ,P_ACTUAL_VALUE                 => V_ACTUAL_VALUE
                                       ,P_WEIGHTING_PERCENT            => V_WEIGHTING_PERCENT
                                       ,P_COMPLETE_PERCENT             => V_COMPLETE_PERCENT
                                       ,P_UOM_CODE                     => V_UOM_CODE
                                       ,P_MEASUREMENT_STYLE_CODE       => V_MEASUREMENT_STYLE_CODE
                                       ,P_MEASURE_NAME                 => V_MEASURE_NAME
                                       ,P_MEASURE_TYPE_CODE            => V_MEASURE_TYPE_CODE
                                       ,P_MEASURE_COMMENTS             => V_MEASURE_COMMENTS
                                       ,P_SHARING_ACCESS_CODE          => V_SHARING_ACCESS_CODE
                                       ,P_WEIGHTING_OVER_100_WARNING   => V_WEIGHTING_OVER_100_WARNING
                                       ,P_WEIGHTING_APPRAISAL_WARNING  => V_WEIGHTING_APPRAISAL_WARNING
                                       ,P_OBJECTIVE_ID                 => V_OBJECTIVE_ID
                                       ,P_OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER        => V_OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER
                                       );
dbms_output.put_line('Successfully created objective: ' || v_objective_id || 
     ' for TARGET PERSON_ID: ' || v_owning_person_id );

exception when others then
     dbms_output.put_line('error : ' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

The call seems to work since it has created a new record in the table per_objectives. However, this new objective is not reflected in the user scorecard. What am I missing. The system (EBS-HRMS interface) does not recognize that new objective.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot

```
commit;
```

so the changes are not visible outside the current transaction.